# Working with sin, cos and tan.

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin \theta = \frac 56$, what are the values of $\cos \theta$ and $\tan \theta$?
I'm have a hard time knowing how to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$
\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1
$$

$$
\tan \theta = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}
$$

You will have to assume $\sin$ and $\cos$ are positive; else there are two possibilities for $\cos$ and $\tan$ and no way to tell which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta=1$ to get $\pm\cos \theta$ and $\tan \theta = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$...

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a triangle. Pick one of the angles to consider $\theta$ and then label the lengths of the sides of the triangle. You can then easily find $\cos \theta, \tan \theta$ by using soh-cah-toa.

Picture: [image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin\theta=\frac{5}{6}$$
So,$$\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$$
$$\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\frac{25}{36}}$$
$$\cos\theta=\frac{\sqrt{11}}{6}$$
And,$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$$
$$\tan\theta=\frac{\frac{5}{6}}{\frac{\sqrt{11}}{6}}$$
$$\tan\theta=\frac{5}{\sqrt{11}}$$
This is very simple.